# Get total number of objects by date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, hash

how can I get an array of numbers of objects by date? Let me give you an example:

`User.all`:

```
id name        created_at
1  Pedro       2016-07-24
2  Juan        2016-07-24
3  John        2016-07-25
4  Matthew     2016-07-27
5  Peter       2016-07-27
6  Jim         2016-07-29
7  Alex        2016-07-30
8  Lawrence    2016-07-30
```

would return

```
{ 
  2016-07-24 => 2,
  2016-07-25 => 3,
  2016-07-26 => 3,
  2016-07-27 => 5,
  2016-07-28 => 5,
  2016-07-29 => 6,
  2016-07-30 => 8
}
```

Comment: It's the result of `User.all`

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this (depending on the database you are using):

```
User.group('date(created_at)').count
```

This should return a hash with Date-objects as keys and the respective counts as values.

It does all the magic on the database-side. Here's the equivalent SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users AS count, date(created_at) GROUP BY date(created_at);
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach could be:

```
User.all.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |item, count| count[item[:created_at]] += 1 }
```

I'm suggesting this approach as I can imagine a usecase where you would need to perform different manipulations of the same dataset that's `User.all`.

Just an idea